Does an internal topos object of a topos induce an "iterated topos"?
From the internal language of a topos, especially the dependently typed version, it seems reasonable to be able to define the notion of an internal topos object.  For example, you would start with an object $C$ of the topos, and an object $H$ of the slice over $C \times C$.  Then the identity morphisms would correspond to a morphism of slices $C \to H$, where $C$ is a slice over $C\times C$ via the diagonal map.  Similarly, the composition maps would correspond to a morphism from the fibered product of $t : H \to C \times C \overset{\pi_2}\rightarrow C$ and $s : H \to C\times C \overset{\pi_1}\rightarrow C$ to $H$, compatible with the fibered product being a slice over $C \times C$ via $(s \circ \pi_1, t \circ \pi_2)$.  Or equivalently, it could be considered a morphism of slices over $C \times C \times C$ of a product of two slices induced by $H$, to another slice induced by $H$ (this version would be more in line with the composition as an element of $\prod_{X,Y,Z : C} \operatorname{Hom}(Y,Z) \times \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y) \to \operatorname{Hom}(X,Z)$).  Then, you could go through the other elements of a topos and internalize them similarly (so for example, I suppose the internal initial, terminal, and subobject classifier objects would need to be global sections of $C$, e.g. $\Omega : \operatorname{Hom}(1, C)$).
So, given such a definition, I found myself wondering whether you could construct an "iterated topos" from such an internal topos object.  This would be by analogy with the situation of (single) iterated forcing, where given a forcing poset $\mathbb{P}$, and a $\mathbb{P}$-name for a forcing poset $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$, you can construct an iterated forcing poset such that if $G$ is a generic filter for $\mathbb{P}$, and $H$ is a generic filter in $V[G]$ for $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}^G$, then $V[G][H]$ is equivalent to extending $V$ by some generic filter of the iterated forcing poset.

If your base topos is the category of sets, then what you obtain in this fashion is the notion of small (set-sized) toposes. That's an issue, because most toposes are not small, only locally small. There are two remedies: 1. Talk about internal arithmetic universes instead of internal toposes. Alexander Oldenziel is one of the experts on this. 2. Talk about "locally internal" toposes.
